# How can I read the value from a SQL query into a variable in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

How can I read the value from a SQL query into a variable in shell script ?
The output is printed into a log file.
The value from the sql query can be different, for that reason I want to catch it into variable to test its value.

The output is coming from a log message function who's printing 3 lines in log file (called 3 times) and the value what I looking for is on the second line printed by $logMsg.

The code for output is:

```
echo "$dateStamp Program: $programName: PID=$programPID: $logMsg $logFunc" >> $LOGFILE
```

The output looks like this:

```
Fri Jul 31 15:06:06 Program: test3: PID=3570: completed EXECUTE_SQL
```

The query value is: "completed", but it can be "abort in process"...

What I tried is:

```
abc=`grep -o completed ${LOGFILE} | tail -2` 
echo $abc
```

But the result is all the time completed. Something is wrong.
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you grep for `completed` *only* (option `-o`), so there is no wonder that you will always only receive exactly this string (as long as it is in the last two lines of the log file; otherwise you would receive an empty string).

You can list all the values you might receive and use an extended regular expression to "or" them (using `|`).  Then you will use `egrep` which understands extended regular expressions:

```
abc=$(egrep -o 'completed|abort in process' "${LOGFILE}" | tail -2)
```

Comment: Your suggestion works well, but the result returned has two values. For example : "completed" and "ready for start" 
I have a pl/sql block anonymous which is doing a select into table and is returning that value.
After that I'm testing the value in pl/sql block and I update that value.
If the initial state of the value found is completed, this will be updated to ready for start and the value returned is:
completed ready for start   

Thank for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just want to print the second-to-last field of the second line:

```
value=$(tail -2 ${LOGFILE} | awk '{print $(NF-1)}')
```

These things would also be easier in general if you delimited your log file with commas etc.